# Navigate to a URL (for opening a web page) from a WPF application

Tags: wpf, winforms, console-application

I am writing a consumer application for [TwitPic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TwitPic) with [OAuth Echo](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_echo).

I need to navigate the user to a web page when they try to get a pin code from Twitter.

How can I navigate them from a WPF form when the consumer clicks a button?

Comment: Are you using the WebBrowser control inside a WPF Window?

Comment: Do you just want to launch a browser, or do you want your app to host the web page?

Comment: do I wanna open the user's default web browser and go to a web page on button click. for instance, go to http://google.com

Comment: Use an InternetExplorer object. It is the same as a WebBrowser except without the InternetExplorer object does not have a window. Add a reference for SHDocVw for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could host a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491073.aspx) control in it's own window and open that window from your button click:

Window Hosting the BrowserControl:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" ></WebBrowser>
</DockPanel>
```

In the click event of your button, use the WebBrowser control's [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491252.aspx) method:

```
Window1 w = new Window1();
        w.Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"));
        w.Show();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. as I said I am using this to get a pin code from twitter for TwitPic pic upload user application. do you think it will work. I will definitely give it a try though.

Comment: yeah it worked. thanks. but how can I do it the other way, I am not sure yet :S

Answer (score 10):

To launch the user's default browser to a specific web page you can do the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://www.example.com") { UseShellExecute = true });
```

Note that I'm setting `UseShellExecute = true`

The default is `true` on **.Net Framework**, and `false` on **.Net Core**
apps. You need to set UseShellExecute to `true` if you want to open a url using the default browser.